# How to build a Shopify app that allows for automatic discounts based on Customer Tags?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Currently building a discount app using shopifys official documentation:

https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/selling-strategies/discounts/experience

The main objective is including an option where I can use customer tags so that a customer under a particular wholesale group gets a automatic discount at checkout based on the tag that is applied to their account.

The main question being, is this possible?

Although I've copied this documentation step by step, the portal to even create a discount isn't showing. I'm wondering if this shopify documentation is outdated. I've managed to find a tutorial on youtube that is up to date and provides me somewhat a starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nQ7C_NM8oQ

Answer (score 0):

Your entire need is accommodated using a Shopify Function. You can read up on those, and discover everything is possible in the use of Discounts and a Function. It is a black box that takes as input your customer, and as output produces a correctly discounted product for purchase.